# No source available for "__kernel_vsyscall() at 0xb779e424"?

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, kernel, system-calls

```
#include <features.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>






#define million 1000000L

timer_t firstTimerID, secondTimerID, thirdTimerID;
double Task2ms_Raster, Task10ms_Raster, Task100ms_Raster;

struct sockaddr_in addr, client;
int acceptSocket;
char buf[1024];
char a[128];
long rc, sentbytes;
int port = 18033;






void TASK1(Task2ms_Raster)
{

     struct timespec start, stop;
     uint32 startTime, stopTime;

        if( (startTime = clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &start)) == -1 ) {
          perror("clock gettime");

        }

        startTime =start.tv_sec + 0.00000001 * start.tv_nsec;
             //  printf("start time is %lf", StartTime);


       // return EXIT_SUCCESS;

    /* Trigger DAQ for the 2ms XCP raster. */
    if( XCPEVENT_DAQ_OVERLOAD & Xcp_DoDaqForEvent_2msRstr( ))
    {
        ++numDaqOverload2ms;
    }

    /* Update those variables which are modified every 2ms. */
 counter32 += slope32;

    /* Trigger STIM for the 2ms XCP raster. */
  if( enableBypass2ms )
   {
        if( XCPEVENT_MISSING_DTO & Xcp_DoStimForEvent_2msRstr( ) )
        {
     ++numMissingDto2ms;
        }
        }
  if( (stopTime = clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop)) == -1 ) {
          perror( "clock gettime" );

        }
  stopTime =  stop.tv_sec + 0.00000001 * stop.tv_nsec;
    //printf("stop time is %ld", stopTime);

            duration2ms = (stopTime- startTime);
           // printf( "time difference is= %ld\n", duration2ms );



}

void TASK2(Task10ms_Raster)
{
     struct timespec start, stop;

     uint32 startTime, stopTime;
            if( (startTime = clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &start)) == -1 ) {
              perror( "clock gettime" );

            }

            startTime =start.tv_sec + 0.00000001 * start.tv_nsec;
             //  printf("start time is %lf", StartTime);


    /* Trigger DAQ for the 10ms XCP raster. */
    if( XCPEVENT_DAQ_OVERLOAD & Xcp_DoDaqForEvent_10msRstr( ))
    {
        ++numDaqOverload10ms;
    }

    /* Update those variables which are modified every 10ms. */
    counter16 += slope16;

    /* Trigger STIM for the 10ms XCP raster. */
    if( enableBypass10ms )
    {
        if( XCPEVENT_MISSING_DTO & Xcp_DoStimForEvent_10msRstr( ) )
        {
            ++numMissingDto10ms;
        }
    }

    if( (stopTime = clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop)) == -1 ) {
              perror( "clock gettime" );

            }
    Xcp_CmdProcessor();

    stopTime =  stop.tv_sec + 0.00000001 * stop.tv_nsec;
      //printf("stop time is %lf", stopTime);


    duration10ms = ( stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec )
                             + (double)( stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec )
                               / (double)million;
           // printf( "time difference is= %ld\n", duration10ms );
}


void TASK3(Task100ms_Raster)
{
     struct timespec start, stop;
     uint32 startTime, stopTime;



            if( (startTime = clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &start)) == -1 )
            {
              perror("clock gettime");

            }
           startTime =start.tv_sec + 0.00000001 * start.tv_nsec;
          // printf("start time is %lf", startTime);

    /* Trigger DAQ for the 100ms XCP raster. */
    if( XCPEVENT_DAQ_OVERLOAD & Xcp_DoDaqForEvent_100msRstr( ))
    {
        ++numDaqOverload100ms;
    }

    /* Update those variables which are modified every 100ms. */
    counter8 += slope8;


    /* Trigger STIM for the 100ms XCP raster. */
    if( enableBypass100ms )
    {
        if( XCPEVENT_MISSING_DTO & Xcp_DoStimForEvent_100msRstr( ) )
        {
            ++numMissingDto100ms;
        }
    }

    if((stopTime = clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop)) == -1 ) {
              perror( "clock gettime" );

            }

    stopTime =  stop.tv_sec + 0.00000001 * stop.tv_nsec;
     // printf("stop time is %lf", stopTime);


    duration100ms = ( stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec )
                     + (double)( stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec )
                       / (double)million;
          //  printf( "time difference is= %ld\n", duration100ms );
}



static void timerHandler( int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc )
{
    timer_t *tidp;

    tidp = si->si_value.sival_ptr;

    if ( *tidp == firstTimerID )

        TASK1(Task2ms_Raster);
   else if ( *tidp == secondTimerID )
       TASK2(Task10ms_Raster);
    else if ( *tidp == thirdTimerID )
        TASK3(Task100ms_Raster);
}


 static int makeTimer( char *name, timer_t *timerID, int expireMS, int intervalMS )
{
    struct sigevent         te;
    struct itimerspec       its;
    struct sigaction        sa;
    int                     sigNo = SIGRTMIN;

    /* Set up signal handler. */
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = timerHandler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    if (sigaction(sigNo, &sa, NULL) == -1)
    {
        perror("sigaction");
    }

    /* Set and enable alarm */
    te.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    te.sigev_signo = sigNo;
    te.sigev_value.sival_ptr = timerID;
    timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &te, timerID);

    its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    its.it_interval.tv_nsec = intervalMS * 1000000;
    its.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    its.it_value.tv_nsec = expireMS * 1000000;
    timer_settime(*timerID, 0, &its, NULL);

    return 1;
}



int CreateSocket()
{

    socklen_t len = sizeof(client);
       // Socket creation for UDP

       acceptSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

       if(acceptSocket==-1)

       {

         printf("Failure: socket creation is failed, failure code\n");

         return 1;

       }

       else

       {

         printf("Socket started!\n");

       }

     memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));

     addr.sin_family=AF_INET;

     addr.sin_port=htons(port);

     addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

     rc=bind(acceptSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr));

     if(rc== -1)

     {

       printf("Failure: listen, failure code:\n");

       return 1;

     }

     else

     {

       printf("Socket an port %d \n",port);

     }


     if(acceptSocket == -1)
     {
         printf("Fehler: accept, fehler code:\n");

          return 1;
     }
     else
     {

     while(rc!=-1)
         {


         rc=recvfrom(acceptSocket,buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &len);
         if(rc==0)
         {
           printf("Server has no connection..\n");
           break;
         }
         if(rc==-1)
         {
             printf("something went wrong with data %s", strerror(errno));
           break;
         }


         XcpIp_RxCallback( (uint16) rc, (uint8*) buf, (uint16) port );


                makeTimer("First Timer", &firstTimerID, 2, 2);   //2ms
             makeTimer("Second Timer", &secondTimerID, 10, 10);    //10ms
                makeTimer("Third Timer", &thirdTimerID, 100, 100);  //100ms
          }


     }

       close(acceptSocket);



       return 0;

     }



int main()
{

     Xcp_Initialize();
     CreateSocket();
     return 0;
}




void XcpApp_IpTransmit( uint16 XcpPort,  Xcp_StatePtr8 pBytes, uint16 numBytes )
{


        if ((long)XcpPort==port){
                sentbytes = sendto(acceptSocket,(char*)pBytes,(long)numBytes,0, (struct sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client));
        }
        XcpIp_TxCallback(port,(uint16)sentbytes);
    }
```

I am working on a client and server architecture. My code is working fine and Server is waiting for a request from the client, when the client sends a request to the server then I am recieving the following message in the debug mode.
No source available for "__kernel_vsyscall() at 0xb779e424"

I am working on linux operating system.

Comment: You overran some local variable (of main), trashing the stack which would take you back to the OS properly.Look carefully at any arrays you have.

Answer (score 1):

might be you have a memory corruption (probably buffer overflow) somewhere in your code.

When you compile with level 3 optimization the code the compiler outputs is such that the buffer overruns writes over something important (maybe corrupts the stack?) and it so happens that the non optimized code produced by the compiler when running with no optimization flag is different so the overflow runs over something else and does not cause this specific symptom. The bug is probably still there and it may manifest itself in other ways or even not at all - until you change something non related and then it will bite you again.

The `__kernel_vsyscall()` thing is simply the a glibc function that is called internally whenever you do a syscall. There is nothing significant there.

please run your program under valgrind. It will most likely find the memory overrun for you.

Comment: i am using two global declaration for the memory as char buf[1024]; char a[128]; where is the option of valgrind in eclipse ? I tried compiling with optimization level to 2 then also same error.

Comment: @user3345539 ok can you give usage of `char buf[1024]; char a[128];` variable in your code.so i can try to figure out or post some code for client/server.

Comment: buf is used for saving the data from the client. memory a is used as a ecu memory in my target.

Comment: I edited my question and added the code !!! Server is the embedded pc target and client is the tool (INCA tool) which is used for sending the data.

Comment: @user3345539 Also `XcpIp_RxCallback` is where?

Comment: there are some api's which is supported in my project and I did not include that code here!!! whenever I recieve a data on the socket I should call that API.